# How to get list of latest entry for each parent using entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have a table named "Children" which has columns like "Id", "ParentId", "Description", "LastUpdate" etc. I want to query a list which will have distinct rows for each parentId and I want those rows latest according to the value of the "LastUpdate" column which is a `DateTime`.
What is the simplest way to achieve this?
I have tried something like this:

```
var latestList = _context.Children.where(x => !x.Deleted).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdate).DistinctBy(x => x.ParentId).ToList();
```

But this couldn't be translated into sql. So what else can I do now?

Comment: You have put wrong tags. Which EF do you use?

Comment: Could you show us the details of `Children` and `Parent` table. In addition, can us include your expected output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your query correctly, for each `Parent` you want the `Child` that has the latest `LastUpdate`:

```cs
var latestList = _context.Children
    .Where(x => !x.Deleted)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ParentId)
    .Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x.LastUpdate))
    .ToList();
```

You can order the children before `.ToList();`